# wordpress htaccess mod_rewrite listing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i use WordPress, and have this link:

```
http://test.example.com/listing/?category_type=Cake&city=Ahmedabad
```

i want this:

```
http://test.example.com/Cake/Ahmedabad/
```

I try add this on .htaccess but

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /listing/?category_type=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule should be, try the below,

```
RewriteRule ^listing/([^/]*)/? /listing/?category_type=$1&city=$2 [QSA,L]
```